# Good PZM / boundary Mics for Sound Design?

Tags: pzm

Hey guys,

I'm looking to add a good Boundary / PZM mic to my mic collection for sound design. What are some good brands / models to consider for sound design purposes??

Thanks!!

Comment: @Jake I'm curious what exactly are you planning on using them for?

Comment: @Stephen Well I'm actually not sure yet. I see them all over articles and books though. Like Ben Burtt putting one on a dumbbell that was attached to the bottom end of a slinky, then hanging the slinky from a latter and hitting it with a drum stick. I believe this is how he got some of the new laser sounds for the newer SW films. Or on the surface of a peace of mettle with dry ice. Or on the ground for impacts, or on a large resonating street light....I don't know if I'll get results, but it seems like a good tool to have on hand because they receive direct sound, and less reflections.

Comment: **surface of METAL. 

Comment: @Stephen YES it's in a sound proof chamber, but it's amazing that a contact mic was able to pickup the sounds of these bugs, via vibrations! Check it out : http://www.sonic-terrain.com/2012/03/how-loud-is-a-slithering-snail/

Comment: @Jake But that sounds more like a contact mic rather than a boundary mic, like you mentioned with the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm a live sound guy, not a recordist (although I dabble).

I like the Crown PZM for applications where you need an omni PZM.

I have a set of Crown PCC 160s for cardioid boundary mics.  THE standard foot mic in live applications.  However, I have heard that Bartlett Mics make very good boundary mics that sound much better than the old PCC160.

Check out their recording boundary mics, in particular.  bartlettmics.com

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the crown PZM.  Its my new secret vehicle recording weapon.

Comment: As in recording traffic and such without being obvious about it?  That's a really neat idea!  I've never taken one of my PZMs out-of-doors.  How does it stand up to wind?

Comment: I've actually strapped one to the back of my motorcycle going 80mph and gotten zero wind + amazing sound.  Also, they work great for crowd and reverb mics.  here's my moto stuff: http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.com/2012/05/recording-my-moto-vtx1300.html

Comment: @Rene is there a specific model you like, or do you agree with TheFaderJockey on the Crown PCC 160?